# How to properly execute Poselib operators? (Pose Library)

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm trying to change poses on my armature with Python and Pose Library, but I'm getting `incorrect context` errors and to be frank I don't even know what exactly am I supposed to use the operators from the docs on.

In the documentation I found this: `bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose(pose_index=- 1)` described as "Apply specified Pose Library pose to the rig; Pose, Index of the pose to apply (-2 for no change to pose, -1 for poselib active pose)" which sounds like what I need.

How do I get the correct context? Pose-mode didn't seem to be it.

Comment: context errors usually mean you're trying to run the ops command from the wrong context, ie, from the Python console when it need to run in the 3D Viewport. You can [override context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) for most ops commands and that will usually be sufficient or you can wrap them in operators that you only invoke from the correct context.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you, I prepared a simple test .blend file on 3.0.1. I'm completely new to context overrides. I understand the general concept, but it's hard for me to come up with working solutions. [poselib_operators.blend](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VeVBPASY/)

Comment: @MartyFouts are you saying it's not possible? I'm using that Pose Library addon shipped with Blender. Is there no way to actually apply its poses with Python? When I check the Info panel it says `bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose_asset(blend_factor=1, flipped=False)` so it's definitely using these operators somehow

Comment: Once I enabled the addon, I was able to figure out the correct context.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: pointed out in a comment: my code needed some error handling and I didn't demonstrate how to use an override with arguments.

Here is an example of how to use an override to allow you to invoke `apply_pose_asset`:

```py
win = bpy.context.window
scr = win.screen
assets = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'FILE_BROWSER']
if len(assets):
    region = [region for region in assets[0].regions if region.type == 'TOOLS']
    if len(region):
        override = {
            'window': win,
            'screen': scr,
            'area'  : assets[0],
            'region': region[0],
            'scene' : bpy.context.scene,
        }
        bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose_asset(override, blend_factor=1, flipped=False)
    else:
        print("Current Pose Library does not have a tools menu open.")
else:
    print("There is no Pose LIbrary open.")
```

The override is inserted into the function call as the first argument, all other arguments remaining the same.

The override argument takes the form of a Python dictionary.  Each entry represents one piece of context to override.  The above example shows the complete override for the command.  Note that the area type is `FILE_BROWSER`.  That is the area type of the editor window that the command expects to run in.

Note:  The command itself uses the first valid entry in the catalog if none are selected, or the active entry if one is selected.

---

`bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose(pose_index=- 1)` is currently an operator designed for the deprecated (but still functional) separate version of the Pose Library system, soon to be removed post Blender 3.1. It exists in the Properties sidebar as a tab in Armature's settings. It requires its own pose entries and `'PROPERTIES'` area type context to be executed. Like so:

```py
import bpy
bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose({'area':'PROPERTIES'}, pose_index=0)
```

#### 3.2 Update

Context overrides are deprecated in Blender 3.2 and are scheduled to be removed in Blender 3.3  The replacement is [`temp_override`](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override). The manual has examples of how to use the new function.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response, but I can't get your code to work. 

I got errors. I was using your code on the .blend file I provided earlier. The first code gave me `IndexError: list index out of range` on line 6, which was the `region = [...]` line.
The second code gave me `context is incorrect` on the `bpy.ops` line. 

I understand that your code searches for windows of certain type and uses them as context for operators, right?

How could I override context on `bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose(pose_index=- 1)` but still control the parameter value? Thank you!

Comment: The error on line 6 is because the search on line 5 didn't turn up any open FILE_BROWSER windows.  I should have checked the len of `assets` before getting `region`.  If you don't have a window of that type there's nothing you can do.  arguments go after the override, so you would use `bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose(override, pose_index=- 1)`.  I'll change the answer to reflect both of those things.

Comment: I'm so close to getting this to work! I believe there's a small mistake in the code above, it's supposed to be `.apply_pose()` not `.apply_pose_asset()` for this particular function. Nevertheless, your code almost works for me with the `bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose_asset(override, blend_factor=1, flipped=False)` it actually changes poses! But I have no idea how to change the active(highlighted) pose. I need something like `bpy.data.workspaces["Layout"].active_pose_asset_index = 2` but for the asset browser. Sidenote, the `.apply_pose()` throws "incorrect context" for some reason.

Comment: @AlexM Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete an awesome response by Marty Fouts, here is a code snippet on how to choose an appropriate asset from the asset browser (tested with Marty's example only)

Inject the original code with the following:

```
space = assets[0].spaces[0]
space.deselect_all()
space.activate_asset_by_id(bpy.data.actions[pose_id])
```

A full example would be (with minor irrelevant changes):

```
def apply_pose(pose_id, blend_factor=1):
    #  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258952/how-to-properly-execute-poselib-operators-pose-library/258970#258970?s=d03c6944322f4034875046fad6b365de
    
    win = bpy.context.window
    scr = win.screen
    assets = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'FILE_BROWSER']
    if len(assets):
        region = [region for region in assets[0].regions if region.type == 'TOOLS']
        space = assets[0].spaces[0]
        space.deselect_all()
        space.activate_asset_by_id(bpy.data.actions[pose_id])
        if len(region):
            override = {
                'window': win,
                'screen': scr,
                'area'  : assets[0],
                'region': region[0],
                'scene' : bpy.context.scene,
            }

            bpy.ops.poselib.blend_pose_asset(
                override,
                blend_factor=blend_factor,
                flipped=False,release_confirm=True)
        else:
            print("Current Pose Library does not have a tools menu open.")
    else:
        print("There is no Pose LIbrary open.")
```

I came up with a solution when accidentally found this https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceFileBrowser.html#bpy.types.SpaceFileBrowser.activate_asset_by_id