# Invalid Context for apply_pose_asset

Tags: python, scripting, pose-mode, asset-browser

I am trying to apply a pose asset to an object and keyframe it.
To do this I followed the approach from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258952/how-to-properly-execute-poselib-operators-pose-library/258970#258970).
I adapted the code for the question's answer to use the newer `temp_override` as suggested.

```
def apply_pose(frame, pose):
    win = bpy.context.window
    scr = win.screen

    area = scr.areas[0]
    area.type = "FILE_BROWSER"
    area.ui_type = "ASSETS"


    region = "EMPTY"
    for i in area.regions:
        if i.type == "TOOLS":
            region = i
    print(region)

    with bpy.context.temp_override(window=win, screen=scr, area=area, region=region, active_object=bpy.context.selected_objects[0]):
        print(pose)
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
        # Alternative for setting active object doesn't work either
        # bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        bpy.context.object.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions[pose]
        bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose_asset(blend_factor=1, flipped=False)
```

The following error occurs: `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.poselib.apply_pose_asset.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

I would assume that the current area for the execution of this operator is the asset browser (`ASSETS`). However, when I try to set the area to `ASSETS` the following error occurs:

```
enum "ASSETS" not found in ('EMPTY', 'VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'NLA_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'CONSOLE', 'INFO', 'TOPBAR', 'STATUSBAR', 'OUTLINER', 'PROPERTIES', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'SPREADSHEET', 'PREFERENCES')
```

**EDIT:**

This was the selected object when the operation was performed.

[image: Object Outline]

Comment: The `type` is `FILE_BROWSER` but you also have to set the `ui_type` to "ASSETS". https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=area#bpy.types.Area.ui_type

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you, I updated the code (also in the question) but the context is still invalid.

Comment: Didn't test it but I think you have to also override `active_object`

Comment: Sorry, but setting the `active_object` also does not work.